# Twitter Bootstrap Drop Down in Html Table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML table where each row contains a Twitter Bootstrap style drop down list. When I click the button to show the list, the menu is not shown due to the `overflow` property of the `div` container.  I have placed sample code that shows the issue I'm having at: http://jsfiddle.net/jpaolini/XgYKP/4/.

The goal is to get the drop down menu to appear on top of everything so it can be seen without have to scroll.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the `overflow: auto;` from `.widget-content` and removed `overflow: hidden` from `.dataTables_wrapper`, and that seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/cnnsB/

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried the sample you did, but that didn't work.  I changed the height of the .pane to be 100px (http://jsfiddle.net/jpaolini/XgYKP/4/).  That shows the problem a little more clearly.  I am trying to get the table to be scrolled while having the drop menu appear above everything.

Comment: @user1483131 It sounds like, in general, you want a `div`'s child element to be scrolled on overflow, but its grandchild to be visible. i'm not sure there's a way to do that. Maybe someone else knows a way

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding position:absolute in your .btn-group and the dropdown will go out of the table. The btn wont go inside the table anymore though